# oracle soa quick installer - integrated server fails to start

Tags: soa, oracle12c, oracle-soa

I have installed Oracle SOA Suite 12.2.1.3.0. The installation process went ok but went I try to start the integrated server I get the following error:

```
<07-Mar-2018 10:27:54,941 o'clock CET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-

000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.> 
<org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger> <ErrorLogger> <schedulerError> <An error occured while scanning for the next trigger to fire.> 
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: null [See nested exception: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2790)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.scheduler.FabricJobStoreCMT.access$000(FabricJobStoreCMT.java:18)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.scheduler.FabricJobStoreCMT$1.execute(FabricJobStoreCMT.java:63)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3760)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.scheduler.FabricJobStoreCMT.acquireNextTrigger(FabricJobStoreCMT.java:59)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:266)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy530.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.scheduler.FabricJDBCDelegate.selectTriggerToAcquire(FabricJDBCDelegate.java:93)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2747)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:71)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "SKIP" at line 1, column 210.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv.makeStatement(ConnectionEnv.java:2206)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv.getCachedStatement(ConnectionEnv.java:1902)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv.getCachedStatement(ConnectionEnv.java:1816)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv.getCachedStatement(ConnectionEnv.java:1809)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:658)
    ... 13 more

<oracle.integration.platform.blocks.scheduler.FabricLockRowSemaphore> 
<FabricLockRowSemaphore> <executeSQL> <No row exists in table 
soaqtz_JOB_DETAILS for lock named: VerificationSessionPurgeJob-QLCKSEP-
DEFAULT>
```

It looks like if it is looking for a table but I thought that this with version there was no database support..

Does anyone have any suggestion?